# ConvertTimeFromUtc calculating 00:00:00 for (UTC-07:00) Arizona

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am trying to calculate the time from UTC to a specific timezone. I am using ConvertTimeFromUtc method for this by passing it the specified UTC time and the TimeZoneInfo of the specified timezone display name. This works for multiple timezones however for -7 it is calculating 0 using the following (simplified) parameters:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Parse("01/01/0001 05:02:00"), timeZoneInfo)
```

However after doing the calculation, it comes out as {01/01/0001 00:00:00} which is strange as it works for other timezones such as Minsk etc

Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry but your code won't _even_ compile since `ConvertTimeFromUtc` takes `DateTime` as a first parameter. Can you please create a [MCVE] to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Updated so that it'll compile. When I stripped out what I have to simplify the scenario (as it is working in other timezones) I forgot that it takes a DateTime and not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hum you have UTC-7 so from 01/01/0001 05:02:00 you are in 31/12/0000 22:02:00
(or 12/31/0000 following the US Format)

```
 TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Parse("01/01/0001 05:02:00"), timeZoneInfo);
```

and msdn says:

The DateTime value type represents dates and times with values ranging from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the Gregorian calendar.

so 01/01/0001 00:00:00 is the first date available..

you have not missing anything, its just a limit of DateTime

sorry for my english

Comment: This is the solution thank you! Rather than using a default DateTime (which is 01/01/0001 00:00:00 as you said) I have initialized the object with 01/01/1900 as the date and now everything calculates correctly. As I am only returning the time rather than the date the date itself doesn't matter.

Comment: @PaulCooney - Generally you should provide the specific date, as many time zones will give a different offset for different dates due to both DST and changes in standard time over the years.  If you only have a time, think about how a user might expect that to behave.  For example, if "today" is the expectation - don't use 1900.